# how to get hyperlinks in iframe from <li>

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am trying to get all hyperlinks from this

```
<div class="eod-rhs">
<ul>
<li><a href="">sdf</a></li>
<li><a href="">sdf</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

above code is in iframe so i tried this but i am not getting proper result.

```
var links = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-rhs").find('a').attr('href').next();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you should execute the your javascript after the page inside the iframe is loaded. for that you can use onload function for example:

```
<iframe id="frametest" src="x.html" onload="javascript:onloadcomplete();"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
var onloadcomplete = function(){
    var links = $("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-rhs li a");
    var hrefs = [];
    links.each(function(){
        hrefs.push($(this).attr("href"));
    });
    console.log(hrefs);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) on the `href` attribute. If you want to pull the next element after any `a` elements with `href` attributes, you'd instead use:

```
$("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-rhs").find("a[href]").next();
```

However here your `a` elements have no *next* elements as they are the only elements contained within your `li` elements.

If you're wanting to pull *all* `a` elements with `href` properties, you'd remove the `next()`:

```
$("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-rhs").find("a[href]");
```

You can then iterate through them using `each()`:

```
$("#frametest").contents().find(".eod-rhs").find("a[href]").each(function() {
    console.log(this.href);
});
```

Comment: @SomeshVyas no worries. :) Please remember to mark this as the accepted answer if and when you get the chance!